# Error Source GPS distance<Measuring Wheel

Tags: python, statistics, geolocation, gps, coordinates

I have measured a few track distances with gps on an Android app and with a measuring wheel for comparison. The GPS tracks were kalman filtered and then the error between KF data and MW compared. The gps track usually shows an error not larger than 5% but sometimes, i have outlier tracks with 15-18% distance error. I tried to analyze the raw gpx track compared to the KF one but can't find anything suspicious. Went through elevation, which was smoothed down a lot compared to the mess of the raw data (but for all of it). What else could the source be and how could i determine which track is errorous without comparing to the MW?
I'm working with python dataframes etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Measuring wheel is also not much precise (has the road flat surface?), so 5% seems acceptable (taking into consideration both methods). Else, you should repeat the sma experiments in the same road several time (and in several days: satellite position, so DOP, is important for GPS). Flat surface with full sky view on all experiments? Did you check on a map? And the GPS was already full operational (so full precision) at beginning?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thank you for the quick reply! I was given the data to evaluate it, most of it was done on the same track (around the same block -i visualized the track on maps in python-) and the road is flat (though the elevation of the gpx data is completely off). Everything should be precise. The problem is, that it's for 6 minute walk tests, so not meant to be recreated several times on the same track. Is there a way to check DOP and consider it in the measurement? I just need to find a parameter that will tell me how "accurate" this test is compared to the actual distance.

Comment: Unfortunately DOP is not written on GPS tracks (it would hugely simplify cleaning the data). NMEA files have it (as most raw GPS data), so if you can get from such files... But "same block" hints problems. Multipath. GPS may get reflections from buildings, and so it may think it is in a different position. It may happens when there are not many satellites on the top. (DOP value may give some indication). Or get a good GPS (so with a GPS antenna, helics antenna helps against multipath), and possibly multichannel (so two frequencies).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, i speculated it was a multipath problem. Since i will only be recording with Android tablets for the actual walk tests measurements, do you have a suggestion on how to determine if my recorded track is mostly accurate or not (since i can't compare it to the wheel anymore to check for differences)? I'm stuck on this issue.. and thank you for your great contribution!

Comment: Some apps in Android can record GPX and NMEA data. Then you have DOP. There are some websites which give you the position of GPS satellites (and forecast for future), so you can check when to do tests (with different distribution of satellites, e.g. try one where you do not have satellites above you.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for the suggestions, i'll see what i can find for now. Sadly, i can't use the forecast since i will be collecting testing data of over 60 people in the span of months, where they are supposed to do testings weekly that i can't monitor. Seems like i chose an impossible task :/.. Thanks for your help as always!